# Group graphs and Ramsey theory. Sub-question 1

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

> ---

**Question:** Find/compute relations between the classical Ramsey numbers and their variations (described below) -- exact or asymptotic.

> ---

A graph is a set $\ X\ $ together with a (coloring) function
$\ c:\binom X2\to C,\ $ where $\ C\ $ is the 2-element set consisting of color $\ r\ $ (red) and $\ g\ $ (green), $\ r\ne g$.

***Remark:** I am stressing the inequality $\ r\ne g\ $ for the sake of my good friend who is a color-blind ophthalmologist.*

Set $\ A\subseteq X\ $ is a red (resp. green) clique
$\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ c\left(\binom A2\right)=\{r\}\ $
(resp. $\ldots\{g\}).$

Let $\ k\ $ and $\ m\ $ be natural. Then the Ramsey classical $\ R_{\,k\,m}\ $ is defined as the smallest cardinal $\ \rho\ $ such that every graph $\ X,\ |X|=\rho,\ $  with arbitrary coloring function $\ c,\ $ contains a red clique of cardinality $\ k\,\ $ **or**  a green clique of cardinality $\ m.$

> ---

Let $\ \emptyset\ne V\subseteq W\subseteq \Gamma,\ $ where
$\ \Gamma\ $ is the class of all graphs. Then we can define
$\ R^V_{k\,m}\ $ and $\ R^W_{k\,m}\ $ just as for
$\ R^\Gamma_{k\,m}:=R_{k\,m};\ $ then
$$ R^V_{k\,m}\ \le\ R^W_{k\,m}\ \le\ R^\Gamma_{k\,m}=R_{k\,m} $$

> ---

Let $\ T\ $ be the class of vertex-transitive graphs.

**Sub-question 1:** Find/compute relations between the classical Ramsey numbers and their variation $\ R^T_{k\,m}\ $ -- exact or asymptotic.

> ---

I'll post the group-theoretic **sub-question 2** later (*it's
very hard for me to edit and post a long MO-question or MO-answer*).

At the right time, I'll include a couple of simple illustrations in that next post.

Comment: @bot, yes, vertex-transitive. (I'll edit it). Thank you.

Comment: The original idea of MO was that a single note-question should consist of just one question. So, that above note goes along that line.

Comment: To me the horizontal lines in quote mode look a bit gaudy.

Comment: @YCor, I am trying to make my posts as readable as possible. After thinking about the issue of taste, and after writing poetry for well over 60 years, in two languages (marginally even three), with a lot of thinking about poetry from different parts of the world written over millennia, my sense of taste may differ from yours.